# I am facing error in pasting an image in Excel from R using package openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am trying to paste an image saved in my folder to Excel using R package openxlsx. I have completely studied the package documentation and followed the steps given in the documentation. But even the example given in package is not working for me

```
## Create a new workbook
wb <- createWorkbook("Ayanami")
## Add some worksheets
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 2")
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 3")
## Insert images
img <- system.file("einstein.jpg", package = "openxlsx")
insertImage(wb, "Sheet 1", img, startRow = 5, startCol = 3, width = 6, height = 5)
insertImage(wb, 2, img, startRow = 2, startCol = 2)
insertImage(wb, 3 , img, width = 15, height = 12, startRow = 3, startCol = "G", units = "cm")
## Save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, "insertImageExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

This is the example given in package documentation. Instead of "einstein.jpg", I am using my ".jpg" file. I am trying to paste that image in my workbook 'wb'. The function "system.file" does not fetch the image I am passing. I have made sure that there is no issues related to path whether image has been stored.

Could anyone of help me with this function or has any verified alternative?

Comment: Your title says that you are using the xlsx package, but `insertImage` is from openxlsx instead.   What are you using?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Openxlsx is the package. It was a typo. Though the codes given in the package are not working for me. That remains true.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `system.file` function as the image that you are trying to paste in the workbook isn't a system file.

instead you will need something like:

```
img <- "C:/your_dir/your_filename.jpg"

insertImage(wb, "Sheet 1", img, startRow = 5, startCol = 3, width = 6, height = 5)
saveWorkbook(wb, "insertImageExample2.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, this is not working for me. The command { img <- "C:/your_dir/your_filename.jpg"  } does not load the image file. Instead it only saves the path into the variable "var"

Comment: That is what it supposed to do. I thought you were trying to insert a plot saved in your directory to an Excel file? `img` variable will have the path of the variable and when you pass `img` to  `insertImage()` function that this should insert the plot to an excel file.

Comment: But the insertImage function is not pasting the plot in my Excel file. I used the same syntax as you have shared.

Comment: Does it return any error message when you run `insertImage` function? And make sure you are accessing the correct Excel file, check where this file is saved at: `getwd()`

Comment: No , it does not give any error while running insertImage function. The code is pointing to correct Excel file. I have confirmed the same using getwd().

Answer (score 0):

For context, you are likely stepping through the documentation for openxlsx here: ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/articles/Introduction.html

The link to the image is incorrect on the link. You should use:

```
img <- readJPEG(file.path(path.package("openxlsx"), "extdata/einstein.jpg"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
    library(jpeg)
    img<-readJPEG("einstein.jpg")
    plotFn(img)
    insertPlot(wb, 1)
    saveWorkbook(wb, "insertImageExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
    file.show("insertImageExample.xlsx")
```

Comment: You are referring to an article that actually creates a function called plotFn. See link here:  https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/articles/Introduction.html